# How to display ntext field data in ASP using Response.write

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

While I am trying to display ntext field data in ASP using Response.write function, it is not displaying anything on the browser

```
ConnString = "DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER=servername;UID=username;PWD=password;DATABASE=database_name"
SQL = "SELECT Summary FROM Sample"
Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Connection.Open ConnString
Recordset.Open SQL,Connection
Summary=Recordset.Fields("Summary")
Do While NOT Recordset.Eof
   If len(Summary)>0 Then
       Response.write(Summary)
   End If
   Recordset.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Where in your code sample should any data value for your variable `Summary` come from? From what you're showing here, you're iterating over a Recordset and testing the lenght of an unassigned variable.

Comment: What are the contents of `Recordset`?  What happens when you try to just write a simple string, like "Hello, world."?

Comment: @Filburt - I establish the database connection using connection string and extract the data using select statement and assigned retrieved column to Summary variable.

Comment: @dg99 - all the datatype values of int, varchar, char, datetime are displaying perfectly except ntext datatype.

Comment: I repeat: Your code does not show that you assign any value from your Recordset to your variable `Summary`. If you do not show the minimal complete example of your code, we will not be able to help you.

Comment: @Filburt - check the code below                                                                 ConnString = "DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER=servername;UID=username;PWD=password;DATABASE=database_name"

SQL = "SELECT Summary FROM Sample"

Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Connection.Open ConnString

Recordset.Open SQL,Connection

Summary=Recordset.Fields("Summary")

Do While NOT Recordset.Eof 
 If len(Summary)>0 Then
  Response.write(Summary)
 End If
  Recordset.MoveNext     
 Loop

Comment: Not an answer to your question the text and ntext datatypes have been deprecated for over 10 years. You should instead used (n)varchar(max). The text datatypes are a pain to deal with.

Comment: Cannot you just do `SQL = "SELECT CAST(Summary AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) [Summary] FROM Sample"`? Explicitly casting it `NVARCHAR(MAX)` which will return like any other string.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done this, but from what I remember you can't get the full value of large fields like that. I had a similar problem adding and displaying images and files stored in a database.

When you're dealing with BLOB/CLOB fields in classic ASP, you need to call `AppendChunk` or `GetChunk` in a loop until you reach the maximum length of the field, depending on whether you're inserting (AppendChunk) or selecting (GetChunk), if I remember correctly.

This is well documented and used to be all over the place, but since so many developers are on ASP.NET now you may have to dig to find it. Search for articles on putting images and/or files into a database, it's the same idea.

I think Scott Mitchell on [4GuysFromRolla](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com) had an example of doing this with a file - just switch it to text and you should be good to go.

I'm pretty sure Scott covered this in his O'Reilly book on ASP. (It wasn't called Classic at the time) If you can get a copy of that book it's a great resource. (He actually discusses the pros and cons of using a BLOB field instead of a pointer to a file in that book)

**UPDATE** Here's the link to Scott's book, Designing Active Server Pages, on O'Reilly's web site: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596000448.do

[This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the Microsoft documentation and should get you started.